# how to create setup file for blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, setup-deployment

I want to create a setup file for blackberry application. I know that I can put the folder deliverables in my sdcard and then installed the application when I click *(.jad)*. I don't want to use desktop software to install *(.alx)* in my device.
But I want to obtain one file or a link to install my application blackberry. In android there is a file *(.apk)*, the user can installed directly and in blackberry how to create the setup  file?
There is a tool to create setup file for bb app?? 
Is that possible??

Answer (score 2):

Hi it is may not possible to create setup file. i will tell you some thing to how to install application in phone.
After signing project successfully we can find two types of files in Deliverables

1)standard 
2)Web

in Standard Folder we can find

1)version number(if OS is 5.0 then we can find it 5.0.0)

2)projectname.alx

open that 5.0.0 folder
here we can find many file types like .debug, .cod, csl, .cso ,.jar ,.jad ,.rapc
these all are configuration files

NOTE:WE CAN FIND ONLY ONE .COD FILE AND .JAD FILE COPY THAT TWO FILES INTO ANY FILE SYSTEM INTO PC

Now open that .cod file and extract the all files into one particular folder suppose in my pc desktop i create a folder name DEVISEDEMO

i extract all .cod files into DEVISEDEMO Folder.

next i copy that .jad files into DEVISEDEMO folder

now i copy that DEVISEDEMO folder into Blackberry mobile SDCARD using any data cable

Now i disconnect that mobile from pc and open Memorycard ----> DEVISEDEMO after that  click on .jad file now it can download all data regarding application after successfully installed one dialog will open.

This is one process otherwise copy all .cod and .jad files which are appear in the web folder to sdcard and after that same process

NOTE: YOU CAN NOT COMPARE ANDROID AND BLACKBERRY BECAUSE .APK FILE SIZE IS NOT RESTRICTED
BUT BLACKBERRY WHEN WE SUCCESSFULLY SIGN THEN IT WILL CONVERT INTO .COD FILES MEANS SYSTEM UNDERSTANDABLE LANGUAGE. impermanent THING IS THAT ONE COD FILE CAN ONLY STORE 64KB DATA. IF IT CROSSED IT SIZE IT AUTOMATICALLY CREATE NEW .COD FILE. SO WE HAVE TO KEEP TRACK THESE INFORMATION WHICH FILE CONTINUATION IS WHICH FILE. FOR THIS PURPOSE .JAD FILE CAN KEEP ALL .COD FILES INFORMATION

For detail reference check following link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Desktop-Software-for-PC/Guide-to-installing-applications-on-the-blackberry/td-p/131589

if i made any wrong statements please correct that

Answer (score 2):

```
there is another simple way to install app in device.
```

1. Joint mobile with pc using desktop software.
2. Sign your Appication.
3. Go to command promt(cmd).
4. use below command :

> **C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde\vmTools>JavaLoader.exe -u load .cod
>   file**
>
> eg.C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE
>   4.5.0\bin>JavaLoader.exe -u load 
>        D:\BlackBerryWorkspace\ABC\deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\ABC.cod

i am using this way to install app so try this it work fine.